# need to display each character with different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

**need to display each character with different color.**

```js
    var str="hello"
    console.log(str);
    var strToArr=str.split("");
    console.log(strToArr);
    var letter=["red","blue","green"];
   
    var i=0;
    var reference=document.getElementById("display");

    var interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(i<strToArr.length){
        reference.innerHTML+=strToArr[i];
        reference.style.color=letter[i];
       
        i++;}
    },2000);
```

```html
<body>
    <span id="display"></span>
</body>
```

need to display each character with different color.

Comment: add span to each character and add color to the span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should solve your problem. Added `<span>` element with `style` and respective color. I added also two more colors.

```js
    var str="hello"
    console.log(str);
    var strToArr=str.split("");
    console.log(strToArr);
    var letter=["red","blue","green","orange","yellow"];
   
    var i=0;
    var reference=document.getElementById("display");

    var interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(i<strToArr.length){
        reference.innerHTML+='<span style="color:' + letter[i] + ';">' + strToArr[i] + '</span>';  
        i++;}
    },2000);
```

```html
<body>
    <span id="display"></span>
</body>
```

So the resulting DOM should look like this.

```
<body>
    <span id="display">
        <span style="color:red;">h</span>
        <span style="color:blue;">e</span>
        <span style="color:green;">l</span>
        <span style="color:orange;">l</span>
        <span style="color:yellow;">o</span>
    </span>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Another probably better approach might be to don't set color at all with JS. I would prefer the `:nth-child` selector. Please review [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) on the Mozilla homepage on how you can use it. E.g.:

```
#display > span:nth-child(0) { color: red; }
#display > span:nth-child(1) { color: blue; }
#display > span:nth-child(2) { color: green; }
#display > span:nth-child(3) { color: orange; }
#display > span:nth-child(4) { color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `span` element for each character

**Note:** `clearInterval()` clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method

```js
var str = "hello"
console.log(str);

var strToArr = str.split("");
console.log(strToArr);

var letter = ["red", "blue", "green"];

var i = 0;
var reference = document.getElementById("display");

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i == strToArr.length) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    return
  }
  let span = document.createElement('span')
  span.style.color = letter[i]
  span.innerHTML = strToArr[i]
  reference.appendChild(span);
  i++;
}, 500);
```

```html
<span id="display"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enclose each character with span tag so you can style each one individually. i have added a colorCounter reset, so it will loop back to red regardless how long your string is.

```js
var str="hello this is a long string"
    console.log(str);
    var strToArr=str.split("");
    console.log(strToArr);
    var letter=["red","blue","green"];
   
    var i=0;
    var colorCounter = 0;
    var reference=document.getElementById("display");

    var interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(i<strToArr.length){
        reference.innerHTML+='<span style="color:'+letter[colorCounter]+'">'+strToArr[i]+'</span>';
       
        i++;
        colorCounter++;
        // resets color counter and loop back to red
        if(colorCounter > (letter.length-1)){colorCounter =0}
        }
    },2000);
```

```html
 <div id="display"></div>
```